# Finding the index of all nearest elements in a table of (lat,long) coords, for given distance function

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude, spatial-query

Given a specific lon and lat point `c(lon, lat)`, and a table `data` that contains a list of lat and lon, we want to:

- calculate the distance between this point to all other lat and lon points in the data and
- return all points from the table that are within 1000 meters from the c(lon, lat)

Tried using `distm` function but we only succeeded in calculating the distance between c(lon, lat) to one point:

```
library(spatial)
distm(x, y, fun=distGeo)
distm(data[,3:2], c(40.706914,-74.011322), fun = distHaversine)
```

Comment: You might be looking for the which() function. For example, to find all elements of a numeric vector that are equal to 5, you would write: which(vec == 5). Hard to know exactly what you need without more information though (e.g., which package does the distm() function come from? What is a specific problem to solve with an answer?

Comment: @MrLister: this one's more complicated though: it's searching for the nearest in a vector of 2D coords, with arbitrary dist function. (It's not just searching a vector of integer/string/factor for the indices of exact match(es)).

Comment: Is that `spatial::distm()`, `geosphere::distm()` or which package? Please make your code example complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distHaversine(x,y)`, where x has the many points (`data[,3:2]` in your example) and y is the single point.

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123)
y = c(40.706914,-74.011322)
data = data.frame(1:10, rnorm(10, y[1], 0.02), rnorm(10, y[2], 0.02))

which(distHaversine(data[,2:3], y) < 1000)
# [1] 2 4
```

Comment: `distHaversine` is vectorized, then? You might want to mention that

Comment: Also, if that requires `geosphere` package, please add the missing `library` line.